# Unable to understand two lines in .screenrc

Tags: gnu-screen

I do not know how you can see the effects of [following lines](http://www.softpanorama.org/Utilities/Screen/screenrc_examples.shtml) in your screen

```
bind ^g  screen -t 'Google' links www.google.com

bind G screen -t 'Google'    sudo -u insec links www.google.com
```

I tried unsuccessfully to press Ctrl-g at a word in a scrollback mode.
I also tried to search clickable words unsuccessfully in my manuals by

```
man man
```

**How can you see the effects of the lines?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To try the `bind ^g` line, press Ctrl-A Ctrl-G.

To try the `bind G` line, press Ctrl-A Shift-G.

All those key bindings work inside screen if the `bind` lines are in `$HOME/.screenrc` and you have started screen after saving `$HOME/.screenrc`. To see if you have screen running, press Ctrl-A V (without shift). This will show you (in reverse color) the version number of screen at the bottom row in the window. If you don't get this information, you have to start screen first, by typing `screen` and pressing Enter.

The get more information about defining custom key bindings in GNU screen, please read the entry for `bind` in the *CUSTOMIZATION* section of the [man page of screen](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/).

Comment: I have screen on and links installed - I can start links in terminal by writing links. - - I get the error: cannot run 'links': no such directory or file, when I run press ^A ^G to a word which I have highlighted in a Scrollback mode by a space. - I apparently do something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you need to hit `Ctrl-A` then `Ctrl-G`.

it should create a new window that executes `links` (of course you must also have it installed) program to browse google in text mode.

`Ctrl-A` then `G` should run as user 'insec' and then run links again.